# ligthen(), darken() in Tailwind for current color

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Have an issue want using the current color for painting SVG to the text color.

But I also want to use 1 color for colorize button and their statuses like `:hover`(darken 10% or current color +100), `focus`.

Unable to find any realization for this.

Is this real?
Now I am using

```
svg {
    @apply stroke-current;
        
     &:hover {
        @apply stroke-current;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tailwind's brightness class.

```
<button class="bg-primary text-gray-50 hover:-brightness-[110%] active:brightness-[80%]"> Click </button>
```

You can learn more about this class at https://tailwindcss.com/docs/brightness